# ionic start myApp blank shows an getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I used `ionic start myApp blank` and I got this error:

```
$ ionic start myApp blank
Creating Ionic app in folder c:\Users\Karimi\Desktop\myApp based on blank project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error Initializing app:  Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:49:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)

Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:49:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26)

getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN (CLI v1.6.1)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v0.12.7
```

Comment: You can copy and paste out of a console. Please do so. Screenshots cannot be indexed and are not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on the GitHub issues [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7348):

> So this seems like a DNS lookup timed out. I don't think this is a npm issue rather than some issue with your internet connection. Manpage recommends trying again later.

Additionally, you can try updating your npm with `sudo npm install npm -g`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an environment variable HTTP_PROXY with http://proxyUrlOrIP:port and IONIC and Cordova will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still struggling, below link solved my issue:

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/04/02/Ionic-Framework-Getting-ionic-start-appName-Working-Behind-a-Proxy.aspx

You need to , 
1. Add the proxy url to request.js located at 'C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\request\request.js'

2. Add the proxy url to registry.js located at 'C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\registry\registry.js'

Hope this helps.